# Is it normal to these Xcode prompts/errors when you deploy to IOS Simulator from Unity?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, unity-game-engine

Just trying out the IOS build process....

Is it normal to see:

Q1 - "upgrade to latest project format - project currently in Xcode 3.1 format, this will upgrade to 3.2" - just click OK and let Xcode do it's stuff?

Q2 - same as Q1 but this time for the message "Remove obsolete build settings - will remove the build setting PREBINDING"

Q3 - also when deploying to "Lastest IOS Simulator" you get the Simulator target produced, but also a non-simulator target which has lots of errors.  So I assume you just ignore this target and not use it in Xcode correct?  (i.e. just use the simulator target that is produced)

Q4 - get a lot of warning after the simulator target is built?  program works ok however....

*Images*

For Q1 and Q2:
[image]

For Q4:

Settings used in Unity:

[image]

Errors I see in XCode:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change target to Unity-IPhone
your sdk version set to IOS latest then you can only run you project on Device

or you have to change you sdk version to IOS simulator lastest
then you can choose Unity-iphone-simulator to run

Comment: I'm not sure if I had attached the correct image, so just in case I've now updated the snapshots in the original post.  I've also included doing an Analyze rather than a build.  Again the app seems to run ok, it's just whether it's normal for a Unity developer to see these warnings in Xcode, and whether to get used to ignoring them so-to-speak.